# Text-box width different between IE / FF / Chrome - Causing issues when textbox is filled with 'W's

Tags: html, cross-browser

We have an application that has a text field with a specified length - 4.

Chrome:[image: Chrome]
Firefox: [image: Firefox]

Is there a way force Firefox / IE to use fixed-width spacing? This is an issue in the case of ID numbers, where the field is actually accepting the full input, but by default not displaying the full width (potentially causing user error if they are typing the field from the screen rather than copy/pasting).

Comment: excellent question and i'd like to get an answer too, Form css is the bane of my existence

Comment: Stack Overflow uses the CSS rule `font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace, serif;` for its code blocks, which would be fixed-width/monospace and might solve your issue. Perhaps worth poking around with it on your form? Text rendering is notoriously different between browsers *and* OSes, so good luck :/.

Comment: By specified length do you mean the `size` attribute?

Comment: Yeah, both `size` and `maxlength` are set to 4

Answer (score 1):

Instead try changing `size` attribute to 5. So in all browsers, it will fit.

```
<input size="5" maxlength="4" value="WWWW" id="txt">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS sector rule

```
#elementId
{
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.elementClass
{
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `size` attribute try pure CSS. E.g. this

```
<input type="text" value="WWWW" id="txt">

#txt{
    font-family: Courier New;
    font-size: 15px;
    width:40px;
}
```

should look about the same in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input size="4" maxlength="4" value="WWWW" id="txt">
```

**CSS**

```
#txt{
    font-family: Courier New;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/pePXB/1/

It's a "combination" of some of the things suggested by others...  I played around in jsfiddle with this for a bit using Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Chrome, and this combo seems to work the best for me, and provides consistent results across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following code
No matter which font family you use, It will make the textbox of specified character width.

HTML Code

```
<input size="4" maxlength="4" value="WWWW" id="txt">
```

CSS Code

```
#txt{
    width:4em;
}
```

This will always make the textbox equal to the width of 4 "M"s so it gives you safe room to use any 4 characters in the box.

For more clarification on using various systems to set width, follow the following link.

http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/5001.htm

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to worry about the code, but please check with fonts that you have listed for 
TEXTBOX are available in both browsers ?

I believe this is what making the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the width of the input element and just retain the values for size and maxlength attributes. It will have the same length all throughout the different kinds of browsers but still have different rendering.

```
input {
     width: 50px;
     padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make some little bit of css in your input text like

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="blabla">
```

**CSS**

```
.blabla{
width: 100px;
}
```

Dont forget to add px after you type size on your CSS.