# Old asp project text with overflow

Tags: html, css, asp.net, webforms

I need to make a old asp project compatible with Chrome.

This is the html:

```
<table class="tabellaricercasmall" width="100%"  height="5%"  border="0">
                <tr>
                    <%--<td class="welcome" width="45%">Società</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="Societa" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Width="100%"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>--%>
                    <td class="welcome" width="15%">Matricola</td>
                    <td   Width="15%">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Matricola" runat="server" MaxLength="10" Columns="12" Width="100%"  ></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td class="welcome"   Witdh="50%">Nominativo</td>
                    <td  Width="20%">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="nominativo" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Columns="20" Width="100%"  ></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td class="welcome"  width="20%">Codice Fiscale</td>
                    <td  Width="20%">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="CodFiscale" runat="server" Columns="32" MaxLength="16" Width="100%" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    
                    <td class="welcome" width="15%">Periodo Da.</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DataDaDropDownList" runat="server"   width="100%"/>
                    </td >
                    <td class="welcome" >Periodo A.</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DataADropDownList" runat="server"  width="100%"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6">
                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Cerca" CssClass="inputbutton" OnClick="Button1_Click1" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Here the results:

[image]

[image]

The top result (with the correct result) is internet explorer 11.

as you can see on chrome the text width is incorrect.

There is a way to fix ?

Thanks !

Comment: reduce the "width" % of the textbox? Or the number of columns? What have you tried so far? P.S. What browser is the first picture from? Some version of Internet Explorer perhaps? Do you still need to support that, or not? Because the real solution here is to stop using tables for layout, and stop using inline styles, and have a proper responsive design. Obviously that's a lot more work but eventually the results would be better overall than just picking at little parts of it.

Comment: yes, if I reduce the width work but the width of textbox is different from the witdth of combobox, If I match the size in chrome , don't match in internet exlorer,

Comment: updated description.

Comment: Try the ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100783/text-box-width-different-between-ie-ff-chrome-causing-issues-when-textbox

Comment: There is more [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome+vs+IE+textbox+width)

Comment: thank you I like to try: where I need to apply the style ? on "table" or on asp:TextBox ?

Comment: Depends which example you're thinking of using. Your comment doesn't show what you're trying to do.

Comment: I like to try this: input {
  padding:3px;
  height:8px;
  outline: 0;
  border:0;
  border-radius:3px;
}

Comment: Well `input` makes the rule affect all inputs (textboxes, checkboxes, radio buttons etc). So that's a rule you'd put in your CSS file, you don't apply it directly to an element. have you worked with CSS very much before?

Comment: not much experience, I need to apply the class "input" to table ?

Comment: No. Read my comment again. it's not a class. `input` affects all `<input` elements. You can't see it in your code because you have the asp.net `<asp:Textbox` style of elements, but when that is sent to your browser it becomes regular HTML like `<input type="text`. So `input` isn't a class, it's an element type. Therefore if you put that rule `input { padding:3px; height:8px; outline: 0; border:0; border-radius:3px; }` into your application's .css file, it will affect all input elements in the application. You don't apply it to anything specific, but it applies itself to every matching element.

Comment: (A CSS class rule, if you're wondering would start with a dot, e.g. `.someClass { background-color: red; }`). That would change the background colour of all elements which have a `class="someClass"` attribute set on them.

Comment: Maybe try a basic tutorial such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps so that you understand what you're working with a bit better, and how to use the examples you find.